# properly join two files based on 2 columns in common:

Tags: linux, join, awk

I have two files I'm trying to join/merge based on columns 1 and 2. 
They look something like this, with "file 1" being much shorter than file 2  and I'd like to find the intersection of these two files:
and in case records not matching, last column needs to be updated with different string.

example below:

File 1:

```
1047    510 75  Live
1048    510 75  Live
1049    510 75  Live
1627    510 75  Live
1628    510 75  Live
1629    510 75  Live
```

File 2:

```
1047    510 75  Live
1048    510 75  Live
1049    510 75  Live
107     510 39  Live
108     510 39  Live
109     510 39  Live
117     510 39  Live
118     510 39  Live
119     510 39  Live
1627    510 75  Live
1628    510 75  Live
1629    510 75  Live
17      510 75  Live
```

Objective: File 3

```
1047    510 75  Live
1048    510 75  Live
1049    510 75  Live
107     510 39  Test
108     510 39  Test
109     510 39  Test
117     510 39  Test
118     510 39  Test
119     510 39  Test
1627    510 75  Live
1628    510 75  Live
1629    510 75  Live
17      510 75  Test
```

Comment: What should the output be if `1047    510 39  Live` existed in the second file above? Should it be the line from file1, or the line from file2, or both lines or something else?

Comment: @Imran - Welcome to SO!  What have you tried to do so far?  You may not get much help if you don't illustrate what attempts you've made to do the merge yourself.

Comment: File 1 and File 2: first 2 columns of each file make primary key and should be used to compare these two files. Compare the records of File 2 with File 1. if record is present in File 1, replace record in File 2 with record found in File 1 If record is not found in File 1, update only the last column of that record in File 2. I hope it is clear.

Comment: I have tried awk, but it fails after processing a few records.      awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$2]=$3;next} ($1,$2) in a{print $0, a[$1,$2]}'

Answer (score 4):

Two approaches.

Use `comm` to get the union and differences:

```
{
    # lines in common
    comm -12 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
    # lines only in file2
    comm -13 <(sort file1) <(sort file2) | awk '{$NF="Test"} 1'
} > file3
```

Or, just stick with awk

```
awk '
    # read and store file1
    NR==FNR {f1[$0]; next} 
    # for file2 lines not in file1, alter the last field
    !($0 in f1) {$NF = "Test"} 
    # print each line
    1
' file1 file2 > file3
```

You can pipe the output through `column -t` to prettify file3:

```
awk '...' file1 file2 | column -t > file3
```

Comment: Hi Glenn. Thanks for your reply. my problem is a bit more complicated.

I have two files:

File 1 and File 2 

first 2 columns of each file make primary key and should be used to compare these two files.

Compare the records of File 2 with File 1.
if record is present in File 1, replace record in File 2 with record found in File 1
If record is not found in File 1, update only the last column of that record in File 2.

I hope it is clear.

Comment: Please add additional requirements into the question.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's|^(\S+\s+\S+\s+).*|/^\1/s/.*/&/;t|;$a\s/\\S+$/Test/' file1 |
sed -rf - file2 >file3
```

This generates a sed script from file1 which replaces lines in file2 that match the first two fields of file1 with the contents of the matching line from file1. Those lines that do not match update the last column of the unmatched line with `Test`. The results are printed to file3.